# Un serviteur attendait-il autrefois (à) son maître?

Tags: histoire, sens

Le verbe « attendre » pouvait-il autrefois signifier être au service de quelqu'un, au sens où le serviteur est prêt à répondre aux ordres de son maître ?

Ce qui me fait poser cette question est au départ la lecture (suite à [une réponse à une question d'anglais](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44452/wait-on-vs-wait-for/44454#44454)) du *Lexicon Tetraglotton*, dictionnaire quadrilingue (anglais, français, italien, espagnol) de [James Howell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Howell), dans lequel on trouve [les entrées suivantes](http://books.google.com/books?id=PCtWAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA2-PA11&dq=%22wait+on%22&hl=en&ei=72WPTsvXA4PItAag9439Dw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=%22wait%20on%22&f=false) :

> To Wait for: Attendre ; Aspettare ; Esperar, eguardar.
>   To Wait on: Attendre, servir ; Servire ; Servir.

En y réfléchissant, le français a bien un sens attenant pour le nom *[attendant](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/attendant)* (sens 2a du TLF), quoique ce sens soit rare. En revanche, je ne trouve aucun sens proche pour le verbe dans le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/attendre), ni dans le *Dictionnaire de l'Académie française*, même en remontant à la [première édition](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k503971/f84.image).

Comment: Entendu ce matin à la radio : _nous avons fait des propositions pour attendre aux besoins de la région_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Le [*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9f%C3%A9rence%3aDictionnaire_historique_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise) complète ce qu'a trouvé Evpok :

> Attendre est emprunté (*atendre*, XIe s.) au latin *attendere* « tendre à ; porter 
>    attention à », de *ad-* (−>à) et de *tendere* (−>tendre) ; l'italien (*attendere*), l'espagnol, l'ancien provençal n'ont que le sens psychologique du latin, attesté en français du XIIIe  au XVe et même jusqu'au XVIe s. (Montaigne), en ce qui concerne *s'atendre*, « s'appliquer à ». Ce sens rend compte du rapport entre *attendre*, *attention* et *attentif*, aujourd'hui détruit.
>
> Les sens actuels de « demeurer jusqu'à l'arrivée de qqn », d'où « patienter » sont propres au domaine gallo-roman ; ils apparaissent en français dès l'apparition du mot (XIe s.), mais ont pu se développer oralement au roman. [...]

Answer (score 7):

[Le Gaffiot](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?p=61) donne

> *adtendo* [...] être attentif, prendre garde.

Et [Lebaigue](http://www2c.ac-lille.fr/verlaine/College/Projets/Latin/dictionnaire_fr_latin/Dicolat-A.html)

> attendo, (adtendo) [...] attendere ut, Plin.-jn. : s'occuper de.

Le verbe latin d'origine semble donc bien avoir ce sens.

Le [DMF](http://atilf.atilf.fr/gsouvay/scripts/dmfX.exe?LEX_ENTREE_FILTRE;BALISE=LEM;BACK;;ISIS=isis_dmf2010.txt;OUVRIR_MENU=2;s=s00372b08;) donne aussi

> ATTENDRE1, verbe
>   Attendre à qqc. "Faire attention à qqc., veiller à qqc., s'occuper de qqc."

Par ailleurs [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wait) donne pour origine à ce sens de *wait*

> Origin: 1150–1200;  (v.) early Middle English waiten  < Anglo-French waitier; Old French guaitier

J'ai cherché *guaitier*, mais la seule référence que j'ai trouvée est dans le [Godefroy](http://micmap.org/dicfro/chercher/dictionnaire-godefroy/gaitier)

> **Gaitier**, [...], *guaitier* veiller, garder

Il y a sûrement encore d'autres sources que je n'ai pas inspecté.

Tl;dr : *Attendre* semble avoir eu un sens proche de *prendre soin* dans certains contextes, plus que celui d'*être aux ordre*. Un serviteur attendait donc certainement à son maître, mais au sens de *to take care of* d'avantage que *devote one's services to*.

Comment: Petite note, _attendait à son maître_ me gène, _attendait à ses devoirs_ non (mais me semble délicieusement désuet).